# Can I remove 'null' from my drop down selection variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a multi select drop down allowing my user to select multiple A, B and/or C options, using react-select. Each time one is selected, I want it to be added to a 'choice' variable to keep record. I have this working, but since I have to declare my variable first, it is holding 'null' inside the variable. How do I get rid of this? Code below.

```
handleChange = (selectedChoice) => {
this.setState({ selectedChoice });
for (var i =0; i < selectedChoice.length; i++) {
   var filter = null;
   filter +=(selectedChoice[i].value); //removing the plus just resets it to last chosen option
    }
  console.log(filter);
  }
```

example of what it prints: nullAC

Comment: " since I have to declare my variable first, it is holding 'null' or 'undefined'" you could declare it to be an empty string `var filter = ''`

Comment: Also you are redeclaring a variable in a loop using `var`. It makes no sense. `var`s are function scoped not block scoped. So you have  only one `filter` per function and assign it to be null on every step.

Comment: Isn't what you want already there in the `selectedChoice` argument to your function? Where do you plan to use this `choice` variable that you're trying to create?

Comment: Never EVER set the variable to `undefined` yourself. It's very bad practice. Also, in very rare occasions you want to set it to `null`. In Javascript, you can just declare a variable and not set it's value (`var filter;`), but in your case I will agree with Yury and say that you can set it to empty string (if the output of `seletedChoice[i].value` results in a string).

Comment: Hi all, the '' works as @YuryTarabanko said. I've just realised it actually logs as:
A (new line) B etc. Is there a way to get this to all be on one line, in one actual string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was posted in the comments by [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko).

```
var filter = ''
```

For good practice console.log would also not be in that position within the code.